# Difference in using self and this in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, this, self

Well, I am a newbie in Python and I am not able to understand the difference in using `self` and `this` keywords in Python.
This is the code that uses `self` as parameter :

```
  class restaurant():
        bankrupt = False
        def open_branch(self):
            if not self.bankrupt:
                print("branch open")
    x=restaurant()
    print(x.bankrupt)
    y=restaurant()
    y.bankrupt=True
    print(y.bankrupt)
```

And this is the code that uses `this` as parameter :

```
class restaurant():
    bankrupt = False
    def open_branch(this):
        if not this.bankrupt:
            print("branch open")
x=restaurant()
print(x.bankrupt)
y=restaurant()
y.bankrupt=True
print(y.bankrupt)
```

Both these approaches gave me the same output. So I m not able to understand why we use `self` when `this` solves our problem. Maybe my interpretation of `self` is wrong. I looked a lot of internet stuff but did not found anything relevant.
Can anyone please solve my issue.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want as long as it's the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in [Python document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks):

> Often, the first argument of a method is called `self`. *This is nothing more than a convention*: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

Answer (score 1):

Using the name `self` is just a (strong)  convention.
You are free to use any name instead, as long as you are constant.
It is highly recommended to use `self` though.

In general, Python gives you a lot of freedom doing things the way you like.
On the other hand, there are many conventions like how to name you variables (compare [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). In 99% of the cases it is best to adhere to this conventions. But if you a 1% case, you can do it differently. I have never seen a case for not using the name `self` though.

PEP8 [recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) the use of `self`:

> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.